# Can the expiration date on a (US) visa stamp be corrected?

Tags: usa

Recently I applied for a J-1 visa which was accepted. I'm going to the US to received training and then come back to my home country. The training is one year long. It's an internship. I'm going with a other person.

I received my passport yesterday and... The expiration date is wrong. It ends on 31/3/2023 but I need it to end on 31/10/2023. My peer got it right.

Can this date be corrected? I got all the necessary documents, the officer just didn't ask for them. She even signed my DS-2019 which it explicitly says that the program ends on 31/10/2023.

I have a lawyer helping me with this. She says it can be corrected, but I haven't found a similar case on the Internet. I'm pretty frustrated too.

Comment: Visa is only needed to enter the country, are you planning on leaving the US during your internship? If not - why does it matter?

Comment: I understand that I can't work legally without a valid visa. And I do plan to come back. My employer offers me to return back after 6 months.

Comment: In the US visa is only to enter the country, after that it's "status", not visa. If you do plan to leave and come back past the expiration - *then* you'll need to get a new visa.

Comment: @littleadv I do have a B1/B2 valid visa. Do you think that I can use that to enter US again? This situation has me on edge... I have been waiting so long... I need the money.

Comment: If you enter on B1/B2 you'll enter as a tourist, not as an intern. You need the correct visa to be admitted in the correct status. One solution would be to not go back during the internship, another - go back and apply for a new visa.

Comment: @littleadv Understood. Do you happen to know if my visa can be corrected? As I said, the lawyer has done some inquiries. I think it can be done, but I don't really know. I would like to come back home after 6 months...

Comment: I have not heard of any "corrections". The issuing posts have discretion as to the expiration, based on whatever internal policies they may have. If your visa expires and you need to come back to the US - you'll need to apply for a new one.

Comment: @littleadv Thank very much for your answers. I guess I'll wait to see if something can be done, if not I have to give up on coming back. Such a shame.

Comment: Can your trip outside the US be scheduled to be within March 2023, so that you get back to the US before your visa expiration?

Comment: @user102008 I can, actually. Thing is, it would be in a very tight schedule. That's why my employer and my lawyer said it's better to try and get the consulate to correct the mistake. I'm open to all options to be honest.

Comment: If you have a qualified immigration lawyer working on your case, they are very likely to be much better positioned to provide advice specific to your situation than random strangers on the Internet. I would listen to them.

Comment: @mlc I'm aware of that. I'm just asking to see if this had happened to anyone. Maybe it's something uncommon.

Comment: Yes, it's uncommon. If it was common your lawyer would have told you.

Comment: Do you and your peer have the same nationality?